# In Kotlin documentation (KDoc), is it possible to link to a specific overloaded method?

Tags: kotlin, kdoc, dokka

Consider the ***class comment*** of this Kotlin class:

```
/**
 * This class has two methods, one that takes one parameters ([foo]),
 * and another one that takes two parameters ([foo]).
 **/
class Clazz {
    /* Foo with one. */
    fun foo(a: Int) {  }

    /* Foo with two. */
    fun foo(a: Int, b: Int) {  }
}
```

I'd like the second link to point to the 2nd function ( the one with the two parameters ).

Is this possible in the Kotlin documentation language?

Comment: Related [bug/missing feature](https://github.com/Kotlin/dokka/issues/80)

Comment: See also [KT-15984](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-15984).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Just found this answer:

> Note that KDoc does not have any syntax for resolving overloaded members in links. Since the Kotlin documentation generation tool puts the documentation for all overloads of a function on the same page, identifying a specific overloaded function is not required for the link to work.

From https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/kotlin-doc.html

... but I don't really understand the reasoning.

Sounds like this makes sense in the context where docs are read separately from code, but most of the time when I read or use comments it's in the IDE UI.